# Python/Cython: efficient regression

Tags: python, regression, cython

I'm working on an algorithm (written in Python/Cython) that estimates the gradient of each point in noisy data, using a variable window size. It's working very well, but it seems that the algorithm is limited by the regression part. Here is what I use:

```
cdef double regression(np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] data, np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] time, unsigned int leftlim2, unsigned int rightlim2):
    cdef unsigned int length, j
    cdef double x, y, sumx, sumy, xy, xx, result, a, b, invlen
    length = 0
    sumx = 0
    sumy = 0
    xy = 0
    xx = 0
    for j from leftlim2 <= j < rightlim2: 
        x = time[j]
        y = data[j]
        sumx += x
        sumy += y
        xy += x*y
        xx += x*x

    length = rightlim2 - leftlim2
    invlen = 1.0/length
    a = xy-(sumx*sumy)*invlen
    b = xx-(sumx*sumx)*invlen
    result = a/b
    return result
```

**Inputs:**

- vectors/arrays of the data and time that was measured during an experiment. The data array contains noisy data of, for example, applied force, the time array contains **equally spaced** time recordings (0.1s, 0.2s, 0.3s, etc.)
- the left and right limits of how much data has to be included for the regression, provided as indices (i.e. the data used for regression is given by data[leftlim2:rightlim2])

**Output:** the slope of a straight line (y = a*x + b) approximating the dataset.

I'm only interested in the slope, not in the intercept, hence the use of a loop rather than regression using matrix-vector multiplications. I was wondering if anyone knows a way to increase the efficiency of the regression, **without sacrificing accuracy**. Perhaps there's a way to exploit the equal spacing of the time array?

Comment: Even if you just throw away the slope, won't the matrix inversion method be faster?

Comment: Last time I checked the SciPy/Numpy solution was much slower

Comment: isn't that y=ax+b?  or does it have to go through the origin?  anyway, yes, you should be able to avoid half the work since the x calc is pointless if it's evenly spaced and known in advance.

Comment: I indeed meant y=ax+b, it should not go through the origin typically, but b does not have to be specified. Using Numpy to solve a system of equations, as suggested by @aganders3, is extremely slow compared to this routine.

Comment: `leftlim2 <= j < rightlim2` is deprecated http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/language_basics.html#integer-for-loops

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Cython syntax, but something like this should speed things up:

```
def my_regression(data, time, leftlim, rightlim):
    timeslice = time[leftlim:rightlim]
    dataslice = data[leftlim:rightlim]

    sumx = sum(timeslice)

    a = sum(timeslice*dataslice)-sum(dataslice)*sumx/(rightlim-leftlim)
    b = sum(timeslice**2)-sumx**2/(rightlim-leftlim)
    return a/b
```

Timing results:

```
n = 1000
data = np.random.random(n)
time = np.arange(n,dtype=float)/n
leftlim = 10
rightlim = 900

%timeit my_regression(data,time,leftlim,rightlim)
>> 10000 loops, best of 3: 74.3 µs per loop 
%timeit your_regression(data,time,leftlim,rightlim)
>> 100 loops, best of 3: 2.88 ms per loop
```

Comment: In pure Python this would be faster, but in Cython it is a couple of hundred times slower. It gets better when using `numpy.sum`, since my arrays are numpy objects, but it still is about 10x slower than the original loop.

Comment: Sorry :/. Also my `sum` calls are actually numpy sums, since I'm using IPython/pylab. Have you profiled your code to see what section is bottlenecking it?

Comment: Without Cython experience I probably can't help you. This page suggests you can further speed up the array indexing by disabling the bounds checking: http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/numpy.html#tuning-indexing-further

Comment: This regression code actually is the bottleneck of a bigger section of code, and is called N times for N datapoints, hence the importance to optimise it (N = 1e6 in most cases). I have bounds checking and wrapping disabled already, so no more free speed to be gained there :(